# Unparseable date: "Thursday, Jan 09 2020; 04:31:59 PM (GMT +05:30)" (at offset 39) in Android 6.0

Tags: android, simpledateformat, android-6.0-marshmallow

Im trying parse a String with a date to convert it into a Date format. Strings are in the following format.

Thursday, Jan 09 2020; 04:31:59 PM (GMT +05:30)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd yyyy; hh:mm:ss a",Locale.ENGLISH);

for(int i=0 ; i <jArr.length() ; i++){
    String tempDate = jArr.get(i).toString();
    dateList.add(tempDate);
}

try{
    Date d1 = sdf3.parse(dateList.get(0));                        
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

**Note: This function is working fine for android version > 6.**

Comment: Have you tried with `sdf3.parse("Thursday, Jan 09 2020; 04:31:59 PM (GMT +05:30)");`? It's working fine in my android 4.4.4

Comment: I have tried but it is actually returning date with addition of  +5:30 which is not expected, is there any other format which is returning without +5:30 ? @Md.Asaduzzaman

Comment: Actually what do you want?

Comment: I just want to convert date from  Thursday, Jan 09 2020; 04:31:59 PM (GMT +05:30) to 09/01/20; 04:31:59PM @Md.Asaduzzaman

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: You need to parse the GMT offset from the string too to avoid getting that false time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your desired format you have to use `SimpleDateFormat` like below:

```
String dateString = "Thursday, Jan 09 2020; 04:31:59 PM (GMT +05:30)";
SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd yyyy; hh:mm:ss a",Locale.ENGLISH);

try{
    Date d1 = sourceFormat.parse(dateString);                        
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}

SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy; hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH)

String desiredString = targetFormat.format(d1);
//desiredString is now "09/01/20; 04:31:59 PM"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this EPOCH_FORMAT in the arguments of SimpleDateFormat :

```
String formatter = "EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(formatter,Locale.US);
```

Answer (score 0):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
            "EEEE, MMM dd uuuu; hh:mm:ss a '(GMT' xxx')'", Locale.ENGLISH);

    String tempDate = "Thursday, Jan 09 2020; 04:31:59 PM (GMT +05:30)";
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(tempDate, formatter);
    System.out.println(odt);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> 2020-01-09T16:31:59+05:30

In order to get the correct time you need to parse the GMT offset that is in the string.

I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API because `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. And because java.time is so much nicer to work with.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.